# Grid 960 - columns too big, causing wrapping

Tags: 960.gs

I might be breaking the 'rules' with this, but for my 960 grid system, I have a few columns that I add a right-border style to them. This has the effect of making that column 1px too large. Thus, if I have a full set of columns, the one on the far right overflows into the next row. This is obviously not desirable.

I 'fixed' this by manually reducing the column's width by the same thickness as the border - 1px. This has worked wonderfully.

The problem is that I just did a demo of my site to a colleague and when they pulled up the site, there were still overflow issues. Columns that looked fine on my computer - a Mac (in Chrome, Firefox and Safari) had the overflow issue on their Firefox browser (running Windows 7). I tried remoting into a Windows box in their office and viewing the site in Firefox and it works fine.

My question is: how do I go about ensuring that what looks right on my computer will look right on someone else's? How is it possible that the same site viewed in the same browser on two different machines both running Windows 7?

Answer (score 0):

To keep the container that has the border from overflowing, wrap it in another container.

For example:

```
<div class="grid_4">
    <div class="div_with_border">This is the container with the border</div>
</div>
```